# Row is not getting updated by using OCI code

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface

My code

UPDATE XXXX SET status = :1 where ar_index = :2

```
//Allocate & initialize statement handle                   
    if (OCIHandleAlloc ((dvoid *)m_pOCIEnv,
                        (dvoid **)&m_pOCIStmt,
                        OCI_HTYPE_STMT,
                        (size_t)0,
                        (dvoid **)0) == OCI_ERROR)
    {
        strErrMsg = _T("Failed to allocate & initialize the statement handle : OCIHandleAlloc() failed");
        AfxMessageBox(strErrMsg.GetString());
        LOG_ALL(strErrMsg.GetString());
        return false;

    }

//prepare SQL statement for execution.
    if (OCIStmtPrepare(m_pOCIStmt, 
                       m_pOCIErr, 
                       pSqlStatement,                //SQL statement
                       strlen((char*)pSqlStatement), //SQL statement length
                       (ub4) OCI_NTV_SYNTAX, 
                       (ub4) OCI_DEFAULT) == OCI_ERROR)
    {
        strErrMsg = GetErrorMessage(m_pOCIErr);
        LOG_ALL (strErrMsg.GetString());
        return false;
    }


if (OCIBindByPos(m_pOCIStmt,
                              &m_pOCIBind,
                              m_pOCIErr,
                              1,
                              (void*)&p,
                              (sword)sizeof(p),
                              SQLT_STR,
                              NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, OCI_DEFAULT) == OCI_ERROR)
            {
                strErrMsg = (GetErrorMessage(m_pOCIErr));
                LOG_ALL(strErrMsg.GetString());
                return false;
            }

            if (OCIBindByPos(m_pOCIStmt,
                              &m_pOCIBind,
                              m_pOCIErr,
                              2,
                              (void*)&m_uiArIndexValue,
                              (sword)sizeof(m_uiArIndexValue),
                              SQLT_UIN,
                              NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, (ub4)OCI_DEFAULT) == OCI_ERROR)
            {
                strErrMsg = (GetErrorMessage(m_pOCIErr));
                LOG_ALL(strErrMsg.GetString());
                return false;
            }


//execute the SQL statement
    if (OCIStmtExecute(m_pOCISvc, 
                       m_pOCIStmt, 
                       m_pOCIErr, 
                       (ub4)3,  //number of times this statement will be executing 
                       (ub4)0,
                       NULL, 
                       NULL,  
                       (ub4)OCI_DEFAULT) == OCI_ERROR)
    {
        strErrMsg = GetErrorMessage(m_pOCIErr);
        LOG_ALL(strErrMsg.GetString());
        return false;
    }
```

Created a Statement handle, prepared the statement, bind the columns by position and executed the query, which is failing.

When `OCIStmtExecute()` function get called, control is disappearing, not returning any value.
Please let me know the solution for this.

Comment: If it's failing you'll see an error, so what is it? If you don't see an error then it isn't failing, so what is the issue? You haven't shown anything after a successful `OCIStatementExecute` call - what are you expecting to happen? (And why is it supposed to execute 3 times?)

Comment: I have modified the code, now its execute once. I am not getting any error or exception, but at the same time values are not getting updated in database. any problem in my code or do I need to add some extra code for commit?

Comment: Do you have any code after what you've shown to indicate that it got past the execute? Explicitly committing is a good idea; I'm not sure if this will implicitly commit or rollback. But does it exit cleanly, or is it dumping core - can you check the return code from the executable?

Comment: Thanks Alex Poole, its working fine now, one more error I am getting while updating the value of variable for which Null able property set as NO. NULL value can't be updated.ora-01407 cannot update to null

Comment: So... the value of `p` you're using in your first bind is empty?

Comment: I have assigned the value, char p = 'F'; Alex Poole, it working now.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci02bas.htm#LNOCI16218):

> If an application disconnects from Oracle Database in a way other than
>   a normal logoff, such as losing a network connection, and
>   `OCITransCommit()` has not been called, all active transactions are
>   rolled back automatically.

If you aren't doing an [explicit commit](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci17msc006.htm#LNOCI13112), and the execute doesn't automatically commit via `OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS`, then your update will be rolled back when you exit the application.

If this is the end of your program then you should also look at [this section about terminating](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci02bas.htm#LNOCI16219) so you clean up properly.